# what's wrong this this help command code? I'm using pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

It just responds all commands but when I type /help command

it says that:

**The application did not respond**

this is my code:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="help", description="Get some help.")
async def help(ctx, args: Option(str, required=False)):
    help_embed = discord.Embed(title="My Bot's Help!")
    command_names_list = [x.name for x in bot.commands]
    if not args:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="List of supported commands:",
            value="\n".join([str(i+1)+". "+x.name for i,
                            x in enumerate(bot.commands)]),
            inline=False
        )
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="Details",
            value="Type `/help <command name>` for more details about each command.",
            inline=False
        )

    elif args in command_names_list:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name=args,
            value=bot.get_command(args).help
        )
    else:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="Oh, no!",
            value="I didn't find command :("
        )
    await ctx.respond(embed=help_embed)
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the description of a command you've created, you have to use the `description` attribute, since there is no `help` attribute.

This is what you should get:

```
import discord
from discord import Option

bot = discord.Bot()


@bot.slash_command(name="help", description="Get some help.")
async def help(ctx, args: Option(str, required=False)):
    help_embed = discord.Embed(title="My Bot's Help!")
    command_names_list = [x.name for x in bot.commands]
    if not args:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="List of supported commands:",
            value="\n".join([str(i+1)+". "+x.name for i,
                        x in enumerate(bot.commands)]),
            inline=False
        )
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="Details",
            value="Type `/help <command name>` for more details about each command.",
            inline=False
        )

    elif args in command_names_list:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name=args,
            value=bot.get_command(args).description
        )
    else:
        help_embed.add_field(
            name="Oh, no!",
            value="I didn't find command :("
        )
   await ctx.respond(embed=help_embed)
```

See https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=slashcommand#discord.SlashCommand